# How to sort fields with elasticsearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to sort results with a title but it didn't work properly.

Query :

```
GET /products/_search
{
        "sort": [
            { "title.keyword":   { "order": "desc" }}
          ],
        "query": {
           ....
        },

}
```

Mapping

```
"mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        ...
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
```

Results

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 826,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1457580605505",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1457580605505,
          "title" : "Étui-portefeuille multifonction pour iPhone",  <-----
          "body_html" : "description here",
```

after googling I didn't found the right answer for my case. maybe because I'm using ES7 and solution giving not compatible with it. 
**I have multiple products start with Z...**  

thanks

Comment: add some of your data as well for a complete understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É is after Z in character sorting. ( É is different from E ). When you want to sort on some string in elastic you should apply a normalizer to your field to achieve natural sorting.

You should go to this documentation page : [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html)

In your case since you use french language, your normalizer should be composed of lowercase and ascii_folding filters. So the example in the documentation page should perfectly match your needs.